# Redirect all subfolder HTTP requests to login page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, security, authentication

I have the "public_html" folder and a subfolder called "login" with the index.php that asks for the username and password.

I need to protect the subfolder contents from malicious bot requests and I thought to redirect|rewrite all the request URIs that contain the "login/" string to the login index.php.

I wrote these lines in the .htaccess inside the public_html:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule %{HTTP_HOST}\/login\/(.*) /login/index.php [L]
```

But it doesn't work because if I write www.mysite.com/login/js/tinymce/something.php it doesn't rewrite anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... maybe its a syntax error of the regular expression used in the configuration file, maybe try this:

```
RewriteRule (login\/.*) login/index.php [L]
```

Also this site regexr.com is a amazing debugger for regular expression
[Image from the same case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXOfa.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar rewriterule on a system I maintain.

Can you try this and see if it helps?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/login) /login/index.php [L]
```

In theory it should redirect everything that starts /login to the index.php file in that folder.